# GeoapifyGeocoderAutocomplete placeSelect property is not working on React TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, autocomplete, autofill

I found an autocomplete address component with free API named @geoapify/react-geocoder-autocomplete can be found on this github repo: https://github.com/geoapify/react-geocoder-autocomplete, the original format of the code is written in react JavaScript but I am currently working on a react TypeScript so I have tried to convert it and the placeSelect property is not working even if trying it to console.log a text and still not showing on the console

This is the original code written on React JavaScript
I have already tested this and it is perfectly working fine

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react'
    import { GeoapifyGeocoderAutocomplete, GeoapifyContext } from '@geoapify/react-geocoder-autocomplete'
    import '@geoapify/geocoder-autocomplete/styles/minimal.css'

    const App = () => {
      ...

      function onPlaceSelect(value) {
        console.log(value);
      }

      function onSuggectionChange(value) {
        console.log(value);
      }

      function preprocessHook(value) {
        return `${value}, Munich, Germany`
      }

      function postprocessHook(feature) {
        return feature.properties.street;
      }

      function suggestionsFilter(suggestions) {
        const processedStreets = [];

        const filtered = suggestions.filter(value => {
          if (!value.properties.street || processedStreets.indexOf(value.properties.street) >= 0) {
            return false;
          } else {
            processedStreets.push(value.properties.street);
            return true;
          }
        })

        return filtered;
      }

      return <GeoapifyContext apiKey="YOUR_API_KEY_HERE">

          <GeoapifyGeocoderAutocomplete
            placeSelect={onPlaceSelect}
            suggestionsChange={onSuggectionChange}
          />

          <GeoapifyGeocoderAutocomplete placeholder="Enter address here"
            value={value}
            type={type}
            lang={language}
            position={position}
            countryCodes={countryCodes}
            limit={limit}
            filterByCountryCode={filterByCountryCode}
            filterByCircle={filterByCircle}
            filterByRect={filterByRect}
            filterByPlace={filterByPlace}
            biasByCountryCode={biasByCountryCode}
            biasByCircle={biasByCircle}
            biasByRect={biasByRect}
            biasByProximity={biasByProximity}
            placeSelect={onPlaceSelect}
            suggestionsChange={onSuggectionChange}
          />

          <GeoapifyGeocoderAutocomplete
            placeSelect={onPlaceSelect}
            suggestionsChange={onSuggectionChange}
            preprocessHook={preprocessHook}
            postprocessHook={postprocessHook}
            suggestionsFilter={suggestionsFilter}
          />
        </GeoapifyContext>
    }

    export default App
```

This is the modified and converted into React TypeScript code

```
    import React from "react";
    import {
      GeoapifyGeocoderAutocomplete,
      GeoapifyContext,
    } from "@geoapify/react-geocoder-autocomplete";
    import "./addressinput.css";

    const AddressInput: React.FC = () => {
      const onPlaceSelect = (value: any) => {
        console.log(value);
      };

      const onSuggestionChange = (value: any[]) => {
        console.log(value);
      };

      return (
        <>
          <GeoapifyContext apiKey="API_KEY">
            <GeoapifyGeocoderAutocomplete
              placeSelect={onPlaceSelect}
              suggestionsChange={onSuggestionChange}
              filterByCountryCode={["ph"]}
            />
          </GeoapifyContext>
        </>
      );
    };

    export default AddressInput;
```

Answer (score 0):

is the AddressInput component being rendered?

```
const AddressInput: React.FC = () => {
  console.log("AddressInput component is being rendered");

};
```

Verify if the context and component props are correctly passed: In your modified TypeScript code, the placeSelect and suggestionsChange props are being passed to the GeoapifyGeocoderAutocomplete component. Are these props are being received correctly within the GeoapifyGeocoderAutocomplete component? Put in console log lines to test.

Same with value prop in GeoapifyGeocoderAutocomplete.

Temporarily remove the custom style file (./addressinput.css) and see if the placeSelect functionality starts working with the default minimal styling.

You need to keep removing code until something works and then slowly add stuff back.

Comment: I have already installed the required packages and yes that is my API key I forgot to remove it and there is nothing showing on the console. @geoapify/geocoder-autocomplete/styles/minimal.css is the default styling and I customize it with my own style named ./addressinput.css.

Comment: How to implement this " also have added the appropriate @types for TypeScript support" ?

Comment: "AddressInput component is being rendered" is shown on the console and I have also tried using the default minimal styling still the same there is nothing showing in the console

Comment: https://andrewarrow.substack.com/p/installing-go-from-source-to-debug